# GCP Vertex Search | Index deployed on Public Endpoint | Error while filtering based on Namespace

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

We have deployed Vector Search index in batch mode on public endpoint in region US-Central1.
It has datapoints with 'restricts' attribute.

We have code querying index deployed on GCP VM instance in same region US-Central1**.
We are using `aiplatform.MatchingEngineIndexEndpoint.match()` method to filter based on namespace.

However it failing with below error. How can we fix this?

```
python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/matching_engine/matching_engine_index_endpoint.py", line 1139, in match
    response = stub.BatchMatch(batch_request)
  File "/home/pravin_jade_accenture_com/vertexserach/vertexserachv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1161, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/pravin_jade_accenture_com/vertexserach/vertexserachv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1004, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "DNS resolution failed for :10000: unparseable host:port"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:DNS resolution failed for :10000: unparseable host:port {grpc_status:14, created_time:"2023-11-02T11:40:59.484628703+00:00"}"
```

1. We have tried executing same code from Cloud Shell , Cloud VM in same GCP Region as well as Windows machine outside GCP. It throws same error as described in issue.
2. We tried using `aiplatform_v1.MatchServiceClient.find_neighbors()` method. However 'request' parameter to this method does not allow add filter on indexes to be searched.
   Are we missing something here?

We are expecting `aiplatform.MatchingEngineIndexEndpoint.match()` method invocation with optional parameter 'filter' to be successful and return matching vectors only.

Comment: match only works with private endpoints it is stated in the comments in their lib:

Retrieves nearest neighbors for the given embedding queries on the specified deployed index for private endpoint only.